Should servers be POSTing my wp-load.php file?
I can see from my Apache logs that occasionally I get POST "/wp-load.php?4897ad=88609" 200 (the query parameter and query value change but are always in that format) from various IP addresses, generally either datacentres or VPNs.
The size of the request vary from being very small (166) and sometimes larger (~4000). Is this expected behaviour or should I be worried?
I've tried searching for the purpose of wp-load but as far as I can tell it's a config loading file. Searching for people noticing similar things yielded no results.
